# Change the way "Improve" button works for edits that have been rejected with change intent reason

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I had an answer get a suggested edit that should have been rejected (the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.)

The suggested edit was rejected by 2 reviewers, but then someone else used 'Improve' and made a trivial change to the new text (code formatting) which caused the edit to be automatically approved.

With this particular reject reason it seems to me the only way to "improve" the edit is to reject it entirely since it has changed the post completely. I am interested to know from the community if you guys think it would be advisable to implement some sort of "Are you sure" type dialog or something when a user presses 'Improve' on a suggested edit that has already received a reject for this reason?

I don't think the improve button should be removed/disabled completely. But I do think something that would nudge people away from it if the suggested edit has already received rejects for the "original meaning lost" reason might be helpful since there are very few situations where there is any valid "improvement" that could be made.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In this instance, shouldn't `user 9000` have just rejected the edit?

Comment: They took the edit and made then formatted it a tiny bit @JoshC. It would be a bit mean to reject if you're doing so little.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I mean, they shouldn't have even considered improving it, as it is changing the answer too radically. They should have rejected it from the beginning and left it - as is.

Comment: @JoshC yes ideally they should've rejected it. That is why I think if there were an "Are you sure?" type pop-up when they pressed improve it might make them more likely to outright reject rather than edit.

Comment: I'd rather get user 9000 banned or warned, rather than making life more difficult for the rest of us. I often click "Improve", sometimes I want to improve other things, but sometimes the edit was just too minor, and other times I actually revert any edit made completely, or at least the bad parts (instead of having to wait for others to reject / approve the edit) (and, in both cases, uncheck 'This edit was helpful', of course).

Answer (score 2):

While this specific edit should have been rejected, unless you can provide some data to show this very frequently and isn't just an a few isolate incidents, then a change to limit this or add more warning messages seems to be a lot of work for very little benefit.

The pro here is you limit a reviewers ability to improve edits or make them click through another dialog message when the other reviewers click a specific reject reason.  But what is the actual benefit?  The worst that happens is a bad edit is made that will usually be seen by the OP or someone when the question is bumped.

On the other hand:

1. What if the other reviewers selected the wrong message?
2. What if there is no or only 1 edit rejection, would this message still appear?
3. What if the users clicks through the dialog without reading the warning?
4. What if the user wants to make a legit improvement to the post and this functionality makes it more difficult and posts a similar <s>rant</s> feature request on MSO?  Should we undo the feature then?

In the end, I see a whole lot of developer time spent on something that has a very limited scope and a very small benefit, and has no assurances of actually working, and makes the edit interface more difficult to use.